# Results within radius - Optimising slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT property.paon, property.saon, property.street, property.postcode, property.lastSalePrice, property.lastTransferDate,
 epc.ADDRESS1, epc.POSTCODE, epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA,  
        (
            3959 * acos (
                cos (radians(54.6921))
                * cos(radians(property.latitude))
                * cos(radians(property.longitude) - radians(-1.2175))
                + sin(radians(54.6921))
                * sin(radians(property.latitude))
            )
        ) AS distance 
        FROM property 
        RIGHT JOIN epc ON property.postcode = epc.POSTCODE AND CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street) = epc.ADDRESS1 
        WHERE property.paon IS NOT NULL AND epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA > 0
        GROUP BY CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street)

        HAVING distance < 1.4 
        ORDER BY property.lastTransferDate DESC
        LIMIT 10
```

table property has 22 million rows, table epc has 14 million rows

Without the GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it runs fast.

Property table often has the same property multiple times, but I need to select the one with the most current lastTransferDate.

If there is a better approach I'm open to it

Here is the explain of query:
[Query-Explain-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtG5N.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things:

- Create a new column so you don't need to use CONCAT `CONCAT(property.paon, ', ', property.street)` in the `GROUP BY` and the `JOIN` (this will speed it up a lot!)
- As JackHacks says you need to create indexes at the right spot. (property postcode and the newly created column, and epc postcode and address)
- Remove the `HAVING` with `epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA > 0` and add it to the `WHERE`

If you need more help, share en EXPLAIN of your query with us.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I have indexed property paon, street, lastTransferDate and epc indexed postcode and address1

Comment: Also using concat, the query comes back in 0.01, 0.1 etc times. So for now I'm ok with that performance hit until I can rectify my main objective as this is what is taking so long.

Comment: I updated it on this suggestion currently (Remove the HAVING with epc.TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA > 0 and add it to the WHERE)

And this is the result of explain:
https://ibb.co/e2x3uc

Comment: The second table only uses 11 rows to filter, so that should not be a problem. If you are able to create a new column for the address to remove the CONCAT. That would help.

Comment: I've just realised property and epc tables both have different collations. Will this cause a major issue? Because it is so large, changing will take time, so am I best changing the ones that I'm querying first? Also, do they need to be the same type? So if I'm comparing epc.POSTCODE and property.postcode... do they both need to be VARCHAR and do they also need to be the same VARCHAR length if so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the database?  If you do, you could try adding indexes on the address and postcode columns (anything in the join clause). That should probably speed up the query.

Edit: reread your question.

If the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses are slowing it down, I would try adding indexes on the columns referenced in those clauses.

Comment: @user3676945 - you calculate the distance for nearly all row in the database and **HAVING** filter this. So calculate a smaller rectangle to exclude the most rows. this bounds you can put it in the **WHERE**. Then you only calculate points in a rectangle of distance < 1.4 and then the filter is quicker. See also the EXPLAIN from your SELECT to see if all INDEXES are there. see http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I have indexed property paon, street, lastTransferDate and epc indexed postcode and address1

Comment: I've just realised property and epc tables both have different collations. Will this cause a major issue? Because it is so large, changing will take time, so am I best changing the ones that I'm querying first? Also, do they need to be the same type? So if I'm comparing epc.POSTCODE and property.postcode... do they both need to be VARCHAR and do they also need to be the same VARCHAR length if so? @BerndBuffen