# ST_Distance_Sphere slow for distances less than 0.5 mile. Is there a way to optimise for finer distances?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT property.paon, 
       property.saon, 
       property.street, 
       property.propertytype, 
       property.postcode, 
       property.lastsaleprice, 
       Date(property.lasttransferdate), 
       St_distance_sphere(Point(-1.3429, 54.5924), coords) * 0.000621371192 AS 
       distance 
FROM   property property 
       INNER JOIN epc 
               ON property.postcode = epc.postcode 
                  AND Concat(property.paon, ', ', property.street) = 
                      epc.address1 
WHERE  property.lasttransferdate >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 year 
HAVING distance < 0.5 
LIMIT  10
```

This query takes around 1.2 seconds with distance having < 0.5, getting much quicker as the distance increases. However, below 0.5 the speed starts to jump up to durations too long for an acceptable user experience.

- HAVING distance < 0.4 - 3.4 seconds
- HAVING distance < 0.3 - 6.3 seconds
- HAVING distance < 0.2 - 10.5 seconds
- HAVING distance < 0.1 - 43.8 seconds

The smaller the distance, the higher the accuracy in some cases, so it's important these smaller distances are more optimised for speed.

**Useful Info**

- Everything in where and join clause are indexed
- coords is a POINT and is indexed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Results within radius - Optimising slow MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434964/results-within-radius-optimising-slow-mysql-query)

Comment: You asked this question again. Put some rectangle around your circle to minimize the rows to filter with HAVING

Comment: @BerndBuffen Not duplicate. The primary function is regarding function ST_Distance_Sphere, which is not referenced once in this question. It's just the database structure.

Comment: can you give me your database for download. then i will optimize the query for you

Comment: @BerndBuffen The database is 83GB, it's got 2 large data sets. If you could Google Cloud Platform, I could give you view access?

Comment: it was good idea if you can give me a read access to the database. You can send me the credentials per e-mail buffen@t-online.de . you can give me also 2 sample query with your execution time to see my query works